# FPDF add new font

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

I'm using the FPDF library for PHP to generate reports, but now I need to use another font (Verdana) that isn't in the core fonts. I added the line:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Verdana','','verdana.php');
```

I copied the files verdana.php and verdana.z to the fonts directory. Every things works fine, if I use the next instructions:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Verdana','',6);
```

But if I try to use the next instruction (to use the bold font):

```
$pdf->SetFont('Verdana','B',6);
```

I get the error:

```
FPDF error: Undefined font: verdana B
```

I tried adding another font for the Verdana Bold:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Verdana-Bold','B','verdanab.php');
```

Of course, I put the files verdanab.php and verdanab.z in the fonts directory. But I get the same error. What I'm missing or how to use both Verdana fonts (normal and bold)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I read through an interesting article on this. It should help you with what you're looking for.

[**Adding TrueType Fonts to FPDF Documents**](http://www.blogbyben.com/2009/12/php-howto-adding-truetype-fonts-to-fpdf.html)

Maybe something like this:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Verdana','B','verdanab.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have added the font directory at the top of the script before require('fpdf.php');

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','./font/');
```

if you have already done that, then just remove 'B' from the setFont() method. Its a quick fix and not a good practice.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Verdana','',6);
```

For more help you can go through this
[Adding new fonts and encoding support](http://fpdf.de/tutorials/7/)

Comment: Guess you really missed the question!

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

`$pdf->AddFont('Verdana','','verdanab.php');`

instead of using:

`$pdf->AddFont('Verdana','B','verdanab.php');`

Answer (score 1):

Standart Font Families:

```
Courier (fixed-width)
Helvetica or Arial (synonymous; sans serif)
Times (serif)
Symbol (symbolic)
ZapfDingbats (symbolic)
```

Here you can create your own .php file for Fpdf:

http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining a font for each style:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Verdana','','verdana.php');
$pdf->AddFont('Verdanabold','','verdanabold.php');
```

Then use:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Verdana','',6); // Regular style
$pdf->SetFont('Verdanabold','',6); // Bold style
```